# tmpfs and vm.swappiness

Tags: linux, memory, swap, virtual-memory, tmpfs

I have started tuning a bit Linux VM performance on my system (yes. I know that vm.swappiness=0 will kill kittens but I found 30-40 as much better for me as it improved my latency - probably  at cost of throughput). I would like to ask how the tmpfs is counted (is it cache or program) for purpose of swapping and `vm.swappiness`.

To give higher level I need a folder which:

- Usually is empty but usage might increase to up to 8x my main memory size
- Do not need to be preserved about reboots
- Is low priority as far as I/O is concerned (i.e. programs using it might wait) but it would be nice if it was fast

Currently I'm using a normal FS. I heard (not tested) about problems with large tmpfs pushing the data on swap. Since I assume that tests were done with default `vm.swappiness=60` and tmpfs is simply occupying only cache the decreased `vm.swappiness` would make it easier swappable during memory pressure. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tmpfs is implemented as cache pages, so a low value for vm.swappiness will make tmpfs files more likely to be swapped out, since the system will favor stealing cache pages over application pages.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @jarno, the Documentation directory in the kernel source tree.

Comment: A opposite explain:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444392/make-or-force-tmpfs-to-swap-before-the-file-cache/444397#444397