# Will the buff cache in Linux affect physical memory, and you don't need to manually clean up the buff cache?

Tags: linux, cache

I use free -h see this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        1.2G        157M        4.8M        630M        635M
Swap:          947M        256M        690M
```

Comment: @muru that's a different question, it's asking about the `buffers` part (seen nowadays in `free -w`), it's explicitly excluding the `cache` part.  I'm not sure we have an existing Q&A that covers this specifically and clearly.  I think we often tend to point people to http://linuxatemyram.com , that's a pretty accurate and well explained answer to the question.

Comment: I might be biased, but if we insist on closing this question as a duplicate, I think the answer on this question would be better: [The remaining question is when will Linux clean up disk caching and will it at all?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451292/29483)